# Example of a non-semiprime ring (or non right semisimple)

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, semi-simple-rings

I would like to find a ring that is left semisimple but not right semisimple. I know that it should be non unitary, and non semiprime, but I can't find an example of a non semiprime ring, I just find examples of rings that are semisimple and semiprimes when I look for it.

I just need an example of a non semiprime ring, but the ring that is semisimple just one side would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may as well go ahead and define "semisimple" and "semiprime" if you are working with rings without identity. I couldn't guess for sure what you mean, in that context.

Comment: Ok, if someone finds this questions and would like to find an answer. or at least an idea, someone told me that the idea was taking infinite triangular matrix, or something similar, hope this info is useful for someone.